# Language about Ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.10, language-support, chinese

If I was to download Ubuntu v.14.10 from [this site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), would the Chinese language be built into it?

Comment: The official Chinese edition of Ubuntu is [Kylin](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin-zh-CN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select Chinese during installation. This image will show up during booting (or can be selected during booting). I assume Chinese at the end.

[image]

But there is a better method: for 100% Chinese (from installation to usage) you need [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin).

> **China’s own Ubuntu**
>
> Ubuntu Kylin is a free PC operating system created for China. It includes all the features you’ve come to expect from Ubuntu, alongside essential Chinese software and apps. Unlike its rivals, its interface has been designed specifically to put Chinese users first - and with new support for touch screens and HiDPI monitors, it runs beautifully on all kinds of hardware.
>
> Part of the Ubuntu project since early 2013, the latest LTS (long-term support ) version of Ubuntu Kylin promises five years of maintenance and security updates, keeping your computer running safely and smoothly for years to come.

[Website to the download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/CN).

Comment: Appreciate your response and answering. I am a Linux user who come from Taiwan(using traditional Chinese) not China(using simplified Chinese), so I might consider using English edition. Still grateful for your answer.

Comment: @林天琥 you seem to be typing it well enough :D :D

Comment: @林天琥, Rinzwind: I don't know how you generated that list of languages, Rinzwind, but when I tried a 14.10 USB stick I certainly could select Chinese.

Comment: @林天琥 updated from no to yes. Used another image for it (my install cut the languages of to the right so I missed chinese :D )

Comment: Yes, I have found that there is a Chinese version.

Comment: But actually English is okay. My native language is Chinese, so I have to practice English more.

Comment: @Rinzwind Did you mean that I type well or bad?

Comment: @林天琥 the 1st! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can select among a lot of languages, including Chinese (simplified or traditional), to be used as the installation language. If you do, the Chinese language packs and language support packages will be installed from start.

If you would select some other language for the installation, e.g. English, you can switch language afterwards using the [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html) tool.

Comment: Is there chinese in the pre-install setup part (I did not see chinese in my version but could be I missed it). I know you can later install extra languages but I doubt that was the idea of the question :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Yes, at least for the installation program (I just tried it). I don't know about the "try Ubuntu" part, though.

Comment: found it! chinese was cut of of my screen; it is at the end. Updated and thanks!